# Combining Code from two programs in Python

Tags: python, pygame

My question is kinda complicated as I run it through my head but I will try to explain it as best I can. I have 2 python codes, one that I created with Python for a Mastermind game and then the other in Pygame for a Mastermind board to play it on. My question is simply this: How can I combine both of these codes into 1 to have it play from Pygame and not the command prompt window I usually get?

I'm sorry if this sounds all gibberishy, but thats my question. I merely want to take my Python code and implement it into the Pygame code and have the game run like it's supposed to.

Heres the code for the game:

```
import random

class InvalidMove(Exception):pass

class Game:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.colors=('r','g','b','y')
        self.to_guess=[random.choice(self.colors) for i in range(4)] 

    def match_guess(self,guess):
        if len(guess)!=len(self.to_guess) or [g for g in guess if g not in self.colors]:
            raise InvalidMove()
        ret=[0,0] 
        usedindexes=[] 
        for i,g in enumerate(guess):
            if g==self.to_guess[i]:
                ret[0]+=1
                usedindexes.append(i)
        for i,g in enumerate(guess):
            if i in usedindexes: continue
            for j,c in enumerate(self.to_guess):
                if c==g and j not in usedindexes:
                    ret[1]+=1
                    usedindexes.append(j)
        return ret            

class UI:
    def make_move(self): 
    guess=raw_input("Guess: ")
    return guess.split()

def main(self):
    print("The game begins...")
    print("Possible colors (enter first letter): [r]ed [g]reen [b]lue [y]ellow")
    print("Enter your guess like: r g b y")
    g=Game()
    while True:
        guess=self.make_move()
        try:
            bp,wp=g.match_guess(guess)
        except InvalidMove:
            print("Invalid guess, try again")
            continue
        print("Black pegs %s"%bp)
        print("White pegs %s"%wp)
        if bp==4:
            print("You won!")

if __name__=="__main__":
    u=UI()
    u.main()
```

And here's the code for the board I made in Pygame:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


def draw_current(men, turn, spacing, corner):
    current = len(men) - 1
    pos = corner[0] + current * spacing[0], turn * spacing[1] + corner[1]
    screen.blit(images[men[-1]], pos)

images = { K_r: pygame.image.load('red.png'), K_g: pygame.image.load('green.png'),
           K_b: pygame.image.load('blue.png'), K_y: pygame.image.load('yellow.png'),
           K_SPACE: pygame.image.load('empty.png') }

pygame.init()

SCREEN_SIZE = (640, 480)
background_image_filename = 'mastermind_board.jpg'
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)
background = pygame.image.load(background_image_filename).convert()
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()

men = []

margin = 5, 3
spacing = [x + m for m, x in zip(margin, images[K_r].get_size())]
corner = 74, 74
turn = 0
quit = False

while not quit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            quit = True
            break
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key in images:
            #print event.key
                men.append(event.key)
            # update
                draw_current(men,turn, spacing, corner)
                if len(men) == 4:
                    turn += 1
                    men = []
                pygame.display.update()
            elif event.key in (K_q, K_ESCAPE):
                 quit = True
                 break

pygame.quit()
```

Any and all help/suggestions would be more than greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you know, you can't just put it all in one file and have it run.  You need to encapsulate the Mastermind game so you can run/update it from the pygame loop.  It'd be cleaner if you keep the Mastermind game logic in a separate file and just import it, but it's not required.

Here's some semi-psuedocode:

```
import pygame

class Mastermind(object):
   def update(self, *args):
      pass #do stuff

pygame.init()

while not quit:
   if event:
      if event == "quit":
         quit = True
      else:
         #update the game
         Mastermind.update(args)
         #update the board
         pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Of course, this won't work for you exactly, but I hope the idea that I'm explaining comes through.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.  Fix your board so that it's a proper class definition.

Step 2.  Write a third file that `import` the board and the game.

They're now "combined".

Now you have to do the hard work of fixing the Game to use the new, fancy Board you built.